# Unable to use Cassandra connector in Presto

Tags: cassandra, presto

I have setup Cassandra, and I've created a keyspace(mykeyspace) and a table to it. I started Cassandra as a service, added the cassandra.properties file like this, in the presto installation files:

```
connector.name=cassandra
cassandra.contact-points=localhost
cassandra.native-protocol-port=9142
cassandra.thrift-port=9160
```

After this I have issued this command in Presto and I think it is connecting to the Cassandra data:

```
./presto --server localhost:9160 --catalog cassandra --schema mykeyspace
```

However, now, when I give the command 'show tables', I get this message:

```
Error running command: java.io.EOFException
```

I would really appreciate any help to clear this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Presto CLI needs to connect to the Presto coordinator (default port 8080), not Cassandra. Change the --server argument to match that of your Presto coordinator.